# How to select layer attribute by attribute and make new layers out of them?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select, splitting

I'm not very experienced with ArcGIS, especially not with coding. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a .gdb of birds. The file is huge and, everytime I try to do anything, ArcMap either crashes or fails the operation. Therefore, I'd like to make individual layers based on the different bird "orders" (taxonomic groups). In other words, I want to split it into different separate layers based on an attribute.

As an extra, I also want to clip each of those with a shapefile of a country, so that I only have the birds of that country.

Comment: I think you should remove the "extra" (second question) and focus on how to "split by attribute" first.

Comment: If you are keen to learn ArcPy using an example similar to your first question there is a paid eLearning video tutorial that I recorded at http://discoverspatial.com/p/arcpy-cursors-split-attribute-location